# Pie chart as marker for MarkerClusterGroup

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am working on a leaflet map that uses `markerclustergroup`. But I want my markers to be pie chart using D3 and to which I'll provide some data.

Here is what I did so far:

```
function getMarkers (){
                 var dataset = [
                 {legend:"apple", value:10, color:"red"},
                 {legend:"orange", value:45, color:"orangered"},
                 {legend:"banana", value:25, color:"yellow"},
                 {legend:"peach", value:70, color:"pink"},
                 {legend:"grape", value:20, color:"purple"}
                 ];

                 var width = 960;
                 var height = 500;
                 var radius = 200;
                 var r = 28;
                 var strokeWidth = 1;
                 var origo = (r+strokeWidth); //Center coordinate
                 var w = origo*2; //width and height of the svg element
                 var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(r-10).outerRadius(r);

                 var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'svg');

                 var vis = d3.select(svg)
                 .data(dataset)
                 .attr('class', 'marker-cluster-pie')
                 .attr('width', width)
                 .attr('height', height);

                 var arcs = vis.selectAll('g.arc')
                 .data([100,10,50,60,75])
                 .enter().append('g')
                 .attr('class', 'arc')
                 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + origo + ',' + origo + ')');

                 arcs.append('path')
                 .attr('class', 'grzeger')
                 .attr('stroke-width', strokeWidth)
                 .attr('d', arc)
```

In this last line I'm getting this error:

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNA28,28 0 …"

I did some research I think it may be related to the fact that it considers data that I'm proving as numbers instead of a string.

Is this the case? Thanks in advance for any guidance on how to mitigate the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the pie layout function with your raw data to get the properly formatted data with the angles needed for the arc function to draw the arc, and then bind that as data to your arcs

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d){ return d });

var arcs = vis.selectAll('g.arc')
             .data(pie([100,10,50,60,75]))
             .enter().append('g')
             .attr('class', 'arc')
             .attr('transform', 'translate(' + origo + ',' + origo + ')');
```

Comment: Thank you @StackOverMySoul for your answer but I'm getting a new problem can you please take a look at it ? [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587179/pie-chart-not-returned-in-leaflet)